# regular expression in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml

Please look at this context.

```
blog:
    path:      /blog/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
```

this is one of yml file example of tutrial about symfony's routing system.
i wonder that URL situation like next pattern.

```
path:      /blog/{page}/{country}
```

in this pattern, How do i write configuration file about requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You should just use variable name as a key in yml file, so

```
blog:
    path:      /blog/{page}/{country}/{whatever}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
        country: \w+
        whatever: \w+
```

The `\d+`, `\w+` is just normal regular expression, you can check more info about regexps [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)